# Ternary Inside Conditional Bad Practice?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, flags, ternary

Is it bad practice to put a ternary inside a conditional?

Consider the following code:

```
        <?php if ((isset($hideEditButton) ? $hideEditButton : true) && $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id') == $user->id): ?>
            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit Profile'), ['action' => 'account'], ['class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-primary']) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

The specific portion of the code I am concerned about is inside the conditional: `(isset($hideEditButton) ? $hideEditButton : true)`

Is there a better way to achieve what I am attempting to do above? I would love to know, thanks!

Comment: Use "ternary" for assignment or obtaining values.  Use standard boolean logic for conditionals, otherwise the readability is shot.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to do this. Your statement

```
if ((isset($hideEditButton) ? $hideEditButton : true) && $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id') == $user->id)
```

could be rewritten as

```
if ((!isset($hideEditButton) || $hideEditButton) && $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id') == $user->id)
```

In PHP 7 you can go even further, using the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php):

```
if ($hideEditButton ?? true) && $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id') == $user->id)
```

The ternary operator in this instance just makes it harder to read the condition. In my opinion, it's especially counterintuitive because you are using the literal `true` in the third part of the operator; it's the opposite of where you might typically expect to see a `true` result (the second spot).

Comment: Thank you for the improvement! Sometimes I go braindead from working too much. :)

Comment: @TravisRowland Been there! :)

Answer (score -2):

Very much. The code goes redundant and hard to read.